# Rust cross-compile -lpcap from macos to linux

Tags: linux, rust, cross-compiling, libpcap, musl

I am trying to cross-compile my Rust project on Mac OS to Linux using `cargo build --target=x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`.

- I installed the binary for Linux + musl cross-compilation on mac using `brew install FiloSottile/musl-cross/musl-cross` as I would ideally want a standalone binary.
- I also installed the target using `rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`
- And I have the following in my `.cargo/config`:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "x86_64-linux-musl-gcc"
```

However, I ran into issues with 2 libraries - sqlite3 and pcap:

```
  = note: /usr/local/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.8/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
          /usr/local/Cellar/musl-cross/0.9.8/libexec/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcap
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was able to solve the sqlite3 linker issue by adding `features = ["bundled"]` to my `Cargo.toml` file (similar to what is described here - https://users.rust-lang.org/t/linker-cannot-find-lsqlite3/23230/18) as that likely built it from source (which was great) but when I tried doing the same with pcap, it gave the following error:

```
the package `myProject` depends on `pcap`, with features: `bundled` but `pcap` does not have these features.
```

After reading somewhere I also tried (with low hopes) of providing the path to the installed libpcap on mac using `RUSTPATH='-L/...' cargo build ...` but that resulted, of course in undefined symbol errors.

Any ideas how can I get past this issue and cross compile my Rust project into a statically linked binary on macos to run on linux?

Answer (score 1):

Cross compilation does not magically take care of libraries. You cannot just say "I want `musl`" and have *something* take care of all your dependencies.

The error message you are seeing is telling you exactly this: it cannot find `libsqlite3` and `libpcap`.

The reason the error for sqlite disappears is because your sqlite library has a `bundled` feature, which replaces the linking with a built-in sqlite client. This, however, also requests the `pcap` `bundled` feature, which does not exist.

You have two options:

- If you do not mind the performance loss in the bundled sqlite client, change your feature definition to target the feature of the dependency requiring sqlite
- If you want the raw library itself, you will have to compile it for `musl`

No matter what happens, you will need to cross-compile `libpcap` for musl with the default sysroot provided by your `musl` compiler. As this varies per library, you will need to consult the libpcap documentation. once you have done so, you should be able to use the `-lpcap` flag, and the error will resolve itself.